# Maven deploy error HTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus

If I use this command I can upload into Nexus...

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=target/common-2.0.0.jar -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=test-common -Dversion=2.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DrepositoryId=TEST-REPO -Durl=https://nexus.xxx.xxxx.net/content/repositories/test
```

If I use this command

```
mvn deploy -DskipTests -DrepositoryId=TEST-REPO -DaltReleaseDeploymentRepository=releases::default::https://nexus.xxxx.xxxx.net/repository/test/
```

I get this error message...

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ common ---
[INFO] Using alternate deployment repository releases::default::https://nexus.xxx.xxx.net/repository/test/
Uploading to releases: https://nexus.xxx.xxx.net/repository/test/com/test/common/2.0.0/common-2.0.0.jar
Uploading to releases: https://nexus.xxx.xxx.net/repository/test/com/test/common/2.0.0/common-2.0.0.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:08 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-16T14:55:35+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project common: 
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact 
com.test:common:jar:2.0.0 from/to releases (https://nexus.xxx.xxx.net/repository/test/): 
Failed to transfer file: https://nexus.xxx.xxx.net/repository/test/common/common-2.0.0.jar. Return code is: 400, ReasonPhrase: HTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL. -> [Help 1]
```

Does anyone know if the command "deploy:deploy-file" uses HTTP POST but the command "deploy" uses HTTP PUT?

Or how I can force it to use HTTP POST?

Note: 
The Nexus version is: Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.14.4-03

Maven version is 3.0.5, and have tried 3.6.1

I found out that...
POST uploads are not supported in Nexus 3. Use a PUT instead.

Comment: What type of repository is "test"?  It needs to be a hosted maven repo.

Comment: I have replaced our Customer's name with the word test. It is a proper repo.  :-)

Comment: Have you checked if the release 2.0.0 is already in Nexus ? Furthermore Have you checked the permissions for your user to be allowed to deploy artifacts ? Apart from that is you nexus behind a proxy like Apache ? If so check that configuration cause the hints about http/put implying something like this..I strongly recommend to remove a proxy in front of Nexus...

Comment: I think that following link should be useful to check how to use alternate protocol: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/examples/deploy-ftp.html

Comment: just ran into the same problem here, except we're seeing the error when using `deploy:deploy-file`; any updates on this one?

Comment: same problem. no answers :)

Comment: I had this problem and it was due to my URL to the repo being incorrect.  e.g. -Durl=$MAVEN_REPO_URL/content/repositories/releases/ (the appended path to the repo had to be valid) ... this may not be your issue if test is a valid repo, but just noting in case it helps anyone.